# Не корректно работает pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

При использование pyautogui , происходят странные вещи. Сама мышка по монитору двигается по указанным координатам, но при нажатии кнопки, с помощью `pyautogui.click()` нажатие регистрируется только на рабочем столе Windows. Почему это происходит , или может нужно использовать что-то другое? Спасибо

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
##
# пауза и досрочное прекращениe
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
## 
sleep (1)
pyautogui.moveTo (400, 1050 )
## Кликнуть по правой кнопке
pyautogui.click ()

pyautogui.moveTo (450, 1050 )
## Кликнуть по правой кнопке трижды
pyautogui.tripleClick ()
##
```

Comment: Т.е. клик происходит в окно браузера, а попадает в итоге на рабочий стол? Для сайтов можно использовать selenium

Comment: @gil9red нет, мне нужно кликать в приложении на пк, но он работает черт знает как, в приложении он вообще не работает, когда сворачиваю и мышка начинает двигаться и кликать по рабочему столу.

Comment: `когда сворачиваю и мышка начинает двигаться и кликать по рабочему столу`, вы запрограммировали скрипт и он делает как было написано -- кликает на указанные позиции ([сам работал с pyautogui](https://github.com/gil9red/2048_bot) и понимаю эти трудности), вы можете добавить глобальный хук на комбинацию кнопок и [по ней включать или выключать действия скрипта](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/992607376ce1f591ca44f8ef43bc1b9eef0efaf9/Final_Fantasy_II__upgrade_skills_bot.py#L89), используя сторонний модуль keyboard. А почему клик не всегда проходит, то хз -- нужен минимальный пример

Comment: @gil9red Я изменил вопрос, добавил код который используется.

Comment: Ну, код как код. можно прикопаться только к "правой кнопке". По описанию функции `click` если не передавать в функцию явно параметр `button=`, то будет использоваться `'primary'`, а у вас, наверное, это действительно правая кнопка :) А по поводу кликов, что игнорируются браузером, наверное, тот не успевает среагировать или в этот момент выполняется действие. Просто по коду ничего не сказать. Можете добавить какие-нибудь проверки и задержки. Но раз вы с браузером работаете, то я бы сделал на selenium, через него можно кликать и не только

Comment: Кст, посмотрите мой пример клика, там используются функции pyautogui для нахождения элементов по их изображению и клику по ним, вместо ручного указания позиции на экране: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/992607376ce1f591ca44f8ef43bc1b9eef0efaf9/pyautogui__keyboard__examples/win_calc_clicker

Comment: @gil9red большое спасибо, но тут скорее всего проблема в программе, потому что даже программные автокликеры не работают :(

Comment: надо питон от администратора запускать